# How to uninstall git COMPLETELY from my Macbook?

Tags: git

I am an inexperienced Git user, and I have installed it according to a tutorial which i dont remember now.

When I type "which git" => /usr/local/bin/git

I tried so many things to remove it, but it says either "no such file in directory" or "permission denied"

Howc can I completely uninstall Git for now?

Comment: Have you tried your commands with `sudo`?

Comment: can you please specify which command? I am extremely beginner with Git, never used it. And also very inexperienced with npm and sudo. Which is the command you generally use to uninstall it?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: @berin Dunno, I expect you to share the commands you have tried indeed. If you cannot remember them, take a look at this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/244001/how-to-uninstall-git-from-the-command-shell)

Comment: Just according to a simple tutorial i found on Google, didn't think that it was such a big deal. :/

Comment: @vahdet I now tried  rm -rf /usr/local/git 
but then again, permission denied

Comment: @choroba it was from https://git-scm.com/download/mac

Comment: @berin back to start: Have you tried that line `rm -rf /usr/local/git` with `sudo`?

Comment: @vahdet Thank you so much, sir! It worked. Now I know that I shouldn't mess up without knowing anything about Git or any other program.

Comment: Welcome! Wish you will never have to run `sudo rm -rf` somewhere again. It's a quite dangerous command indeed and requires extra caution.